# How to know if app is launch from voice trigger

Tags: google-glass

There is a way, to know if an app was started with "ok glass app" voice trigger, or if you made the click on the glass list apps?

something like an extra on the intent, to know if the app was launched with voice trigger or with a touch.

This mean, that I want to know my main activity must to launch more commands voices listener or not.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but a possible approach for solving your problem. You could create a launcher app that would be triggered only from voice. This app simply would launch your main app with command line arguments to enable voice commands. So, for example, let's suppose your app is called 'Foo' and the launcher 'VoiceFoo'. To launch the app from the menu, just click on 'Foo' and to trigger from voice just say "ok glass voicefoo".

"listenfoo" would also be a good name for the launcher app ;-)

Comment: I know what is your work arround, but this would create two launcher one to the real main app, and the other to the foo ... this is a little ugly becouse you have like ... two apps. Is there a way to hide the "foo" one, from the list of apps? to only let it launched with voice? and made the same to the no-voice app... to don't let it be shown on the voice trigger menu?